# In lsof output what are those 'sock' lines?

Tags: lsof

In lsof command under Ubuntu/Debian, I'm seeing a lot of lines like below:

```
PROGRAM 829 root  140u     sock        0,8       0t0 244182 protocol: TCP
```

What are these lines?

**Can they be results of failed TCP connection attempts?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is displayed when `lsof` cannot find additional informations on the TCP socket: it knows it's a TCP socket but not more.

There are two reasons I can think of:

- Unlikely: the socket is still not listening nor connecting: ie a server or client used for example [`socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/socket.2) to create a TCP socket but didn't call yet [`listen(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/listen.2) or [`connect(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/connect.2). This could be caused by lack of resources or a buggy software.
- Most likely today: the process seen by `lsof` runs in an other [network namespace](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/network_namespaces.7), typically in a container (Docker, LXC, LXD ...) and thus `lsof` doesn't have access to the relevant information and doesn't display it.

  You should then run `lsof` from the same network namespace as the process. The [`lsns`](https://manpages.debian.org/util-linux/lsns.8) and [`nsenter`](https://manpages.debian.org/util-linux/nsenter) commands can greatly help for this. For your case this would then probably work:

  ```
    nsenter -t 829 --net lsof -n -p 829
  ```

In normal cases `lsof` would display `IPv4` or `IPv6` instead of `sock` and would have additional informations, like listening port or addresses involved. Even a connection still ongoing would be displayed with the addresses involved and for example `SYN_SENT`.